# Why does Windows 10 uses so much RAM and CPU?

Tags: windows-10, memory

I have Windows 10, and nowadays as I use my laptop, my computer uses more and more RAM and CPU. If I don't do anything, happens the same, I left my laptop at home, and after 8-10 hours it uses 99% of my hardwares, and after a while my computer freezes and says, that I have to restart my computer, because I have no more RAM. I don't have any viruses, and yes, I disabled Superfetch also. The top 2, which uses, are always Service Host: Local System (mainly this one) and System.

Here's a picture after 10 minutes of run:

[image: https://postimg.org/image/brggjvoz7/]

And here after 2 hours:

[image: https://postimg.cc/image/68nr59azn/]

Expanded as requested:

[image]

Comment: Please expand the entry so that we can see the services the process hosts.

Comment: This is not a duplicate. Windows compressing the memory is just a result of the original problem: a service eating memory.

Comment: https://postimg.org/image/jftexoc69/

Comment: Hm, interesting. Try stopping the Windows Update service.

Comment: Try the process [here](http://www.windowscentral.com/how-use-dism-command-line-utility-repair-windows-10-image).

Comment: Nothing helped yet :/

Comment: reboot, open a cmd.exe as admin and run this: **wpr.exe -start  CPU -start ReferenceSet && timeout -1 wpr.exe -stop C:\HighCPUAndMemoryUsage.etl**. (Attention, this command must be 1 line without any line breaks) Minimize the cmd Window, let this run a few minutes until you see a memory usage grow. if you captured the grow, go to the cmd again, press a key to stop logging. compress the etl and share it.

Comment: ok, I have a mistake in the command. use this on: **wpr.exe -start CPU -start ReferenceSet -filemode && timeout -1 && wpr.exe -stop C:\HighCPUAndMemoryUsage.etl**

Comment: It's ridiculous this is marked as a duplicate. The service host process (`svchost`) is not the System process.

Answer (score 1):

While I can't translate what program is taking all the memory, I imagine it's the feature of Windows 10 that puts used files into memory to allow for faster access should you re-start the program that needs them.  It's nothing particularly to worry about since Windows will just free the memory if you open something else.

Remember that unused memory is wasted memory.  So Windows uses it whenever it can.

Comment: You should quote the relevant information from your link

Comment: Link removed as it only referred to Windows XP and 7 and not Windows 10 to which this question refers.

Comment: I am not sure it makes a difference here.  Memory mangement hasn't change that much, only difference between Windows 7 and Windows 10 would be that memory is not compressed.  The article is pretty version netural, I see no reason, it wouldn't apply to Windows 10.

Comment: This is not cache or anything. That memory is really used. It’s a memory leak.

Comment: @DanielB How did you reach that conclusion? This looks like normal Windows 10 caching and compression to me.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Because no form of caching or whatever results in the Local System service host using that much memory. (It’s at 25 MiB here.) Memory used for cache isn’t attributed to any process but displayed as free. Compressed memory is displayed on the System process. Yet in this case it’s clearly the Local System service host using all memory.

Comment: @DanielB Memory used for cache is *never* displayed as free, since it's not free. There are caches and discardable memory all over the place in modern Windows systems. There's no evidence of a leak here.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Okay maybe my wording was bad, but please take a look at Task Manager’s memory view. Cached (aka standby) memory is “available”. Windows has carefully designed it so as not to confuse novice users. The percentage in Task Manager clearly indicates there is (almost) *no* “available” memory left. Task Manager also clearly indicates the process using the memory: The Local System service host. This process is *not* supposed to use that much memory. It *does not* host any cache. It *does not* host compressed memory.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how, but now my computer works like nothing happened. The RAM and the CPU as well, don't know how or why. If anybody else has this problem, the Microsoft recommended me the following steps:

- Delete Avast antivirus https://www.avast.com/uninstall-utility
- Search for viruses by the windows Defender
- Delete all the "malware search" programs, including CCleaner
- If after all these steps you still have the problem, try this:

  - Open Command line as administrator (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>)
  - Type these and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> after all the lines

    ```
    dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /ScanHealth
    dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /CheckHealth
    dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth
    ```

I hope I could help you!

Comment: If you’re still around: Please mark an answer as accepted. It can be your own answer!